# Should I use full sentence after like in the sentence below

Tags: meaning

When my cousin cries he seems like he laughs.When I describe this situation can say sententence below without using full sentence after “like “.

> My cousin cries like laughing

Or should I say by using full sentence after “like”

> My cousin cries like he laughs.

Comment: First sentence sounds a bit off to me. Second one is probably the best choice here.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence doesn't work at all. The second would probably be interpreted in the sense that you intend although some people might ask you what you mean by it.